# Is there something special to encrypting a string into another file using a custom dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, file, dictionary, encryption-symmetric

I made a custom dictionary in **Python** changing the alphabet (both upper and lowercase) into symbols and numbers.  I am trying to copy the content of one text file to another but encrypt it in the custom dictionary.  For example, if the file says "Hello World" the other file that it is being copied to should say "%?;;2 !2(;". I tried a bunch of things but it either gives me an error or the other file stays blank

Here's the code below

```
fileData = open('EXAMPLE.txt', 'r')
f = open('ENCODE.txt', 'w')

for x in fileData:
    encrypt = code.get(x, '')
    f.write(encrypt)
```

fileData is the file the is being read/ copied from.  code is the dictionary name.  Then I tried getting the value from the key or if it is a number/ white space, it will just default. However, it keeps coming out blank.  I tried the import json but I also can not get that to encrypt with the dictionary.

EXAMPLE.txt has the text

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
```

ENCODE.txt is blank as the text will be copied over and encoded

Dictionary below

```
code = {'A':'1',
         'a':'@',
         'B':'!',
         'b':'#',
         'C':'3',
         'c':'$',
         'D':'4',
         'd':'^',
         'E':'<',
         'e':'?',
         'F':'>',
         'f':',',
         'G':'5',
         'g':'/',
         'H':'%',
         'h':']',
         'I':'[',
         'i':'£',
         'J':'|',
         'j':'*',
         'K':'-',
         'k':'+',
         'L':'8',
         'l':')',
         'M':'9',
         'm':'(',
         'N':'&',
         'n':'7',
         'O':';',
         'o':'`',
         'P':'0',
         'p':'_',
         'Q':'"',
         'q':'~',
         'R':'.',
         'r':'2',
         'S':'6',
         's':'8',
         'T':'7',
         't':'=',
         'U':'[',
         'u':'>',
         'V':'{',
         'v':';',
         'W':'}',
         'w':':',
         'X':'é',
         'x':'¡',
         'Y':'»',
         'y':'¤',
         'Z':'§',
         'z':'µ'}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'm not too sure how much I can simplify it.  It opens a .txt file, reads it,  copies it to another file,  lastly it encodes it in the other file.   Not too sure if that helps any.  I didn't include the dictionary as it is 52 keys and values.  If it would help let me know.

Comment: What's in `EXAMPLE.txt` and `ENCODE.txt`? It's hard to give a clear suggestion if you can't give us information on what you've tried so far.

Comment: I can see that you're not closing the file after you're done writing to it, which you should address by using `f.close()`, but without seeing the file contents I'm not sure about the error you're describing.

Comment: In EXAMPLE.txt just a sentence 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG'

In ENCODE.txt is just blank  

The contents of EXAMPLE should be copied into ENCODE and then encoded but it just stays blank or copies without being encoded

Comment: And what's in the custom dictionary? Again, your example needs to be _reproducible_: I should be able to produce the issue you're facing myself with only the information you've provided.

Comment: Alright, I think I have a candidate solution, but the mapping between "Hello world" and "%?;;2 !2(;" doesn't appear to be correct upon inspection of the `code` dictionary -- can you make sure this is correct?

Comment: `for x in fileData:`.  This reads a *line* of text, so `x` isn't a single character.  Use a source debugger or a print statement to understand what your code is doing.  Also see [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for an easier way to code this.

Comment: I wanted to change it but it kept reading it as a code and I thought that would be confusing as it would appear as %?))` }`2)4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for x in fileData:` iterates *lines* of text.  You need something like the following to read a single character at a time:

```
while (x := fileData.read(1)):
```

But there is also `str.translate` and `str.maketrans` which are built-in methods of string to generate lookup tables and perform translation, so you can read the whole file and translate efficiently:

Python 3.10 example:

```py
xlat = str.maketrans('AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz',
                     '1@!#3$4^<?>,5/%][£|*-+8)9(&7;`0_"~.2687=[>{;}:é¡»¤§µ')

with (open('EXAMPLE.txt', 'r') as fileData,
      open('ENCODE.txt', 'w') as f):

    encrypt = fileData.read().translate(xlat)
    f.write(encrypt)
```